# JQuery GET request returns missing CORS origin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors, web-config

OK, I have 3 servers that need to communicate together for a GET request. But I keep getting the origin is missing error, I can see the information that I want to receive in postman (so I know that my url's and passing on information works).

1. Server with a public website from which the request starts (JQuery), this is on a different domain then the next 2 servers.
2. Security server with application, to make sure that the database doesn't have a direct link with the public website.
3. Server with the same as server 2 application + main application & database (I have been made aware that this server is irrelevant for cors)

JQuery

```
function GetData(nummer, insz) {
    showLoader(true);
    var func = function (host) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: host + "/api/GetList/" + number + "/" + version + "/" + typeId + "/" + extraPriority,
            error: function () { alert('ERROR'); showLoader(false); showEmptyTableMessage(true); }
        }).then(function (data) {
            drawTable(data);
            showLoader(false);
        });
    };

    func(URLTOSERVER);

    FindServerUrlAsync(func);
}

function FindServerUrlAsync(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/settings/ServerType"
    }).then(function (serverType) {
        var isDmz = (serverType === 'Dmz');
        if (isDmz) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/settings/ServerUrl"
            }).then(function (serverUrl) {
                callback(serverUrl);
            });
        } else {
            callback("");
        }
    });
}
```

The second server goes into a asp.net application controller (mvc) that uses an async request from an httpclient from the database.

web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

ASP.NET Startup

```
var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader();
corsBuilder.AllowAnyMethod();
corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin();
corsBuilder.AllowCredentials();

services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", corsBuilder.Build());
});

app.UseCors("AllowAll");
```

The request goes into the same asp.net application controller only in a different method / action (and obviously server). The web.config doesn't have a httprotocol (since I have been made aware that it's unnecessary).

I have been looking at this for a while now. But I can't seem to get it to work.

Edited

Comment: Are you doing a redirect from ajax endpoint to other server ?

Comment: No, its JQuery -> httpclient in asp.net -> entity framework context for the database.

Comment: Mentioning third server is confusing then because it isn't directly relevant to request between client and server. Why is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` commented out? That is the first and most important header that must exist. Also might change `*` to valid origin

Comment: I have tried it multiple times with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard on. Its a no go. Tried it with both on or one of each. Tried it with the origin that I send from the website as the value too. (Uncommented it, to avoid confusion)

Comment: It's the server which the jQuery code is making the cross-domain ajax request to which needs to return the CORS headers to the browser. A HTTP request between from a non-brower application (from the first server to the second server, or from Postman to any server) is not subject to CORS restrictions. It's not clear from your description which server it is which contains the CORS code.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. So it would be fine to disable the web.config cors configuration from the database server? What about the cors configuration in the application?

Comment: Yes, if no-one ever makes cross-domain ajax requests directly to it. But why has the database server got C# code on it? Surely it just has a database on it? Conventionally you wouldn't host a web app and database on the same physical server, unless you're doing containerised microservices or something.

Comment: The final server has the application for the request of the public website. And the main website application + database. Do you think it would it we better to make the httprequest to the main website application?

Comment: I don't know, you need to make your HTTP requests to wherever the functionality you require is deployed. I was more asking from an architecture point of view, about the wisdom of hosting apps and databases on the same server (I made this assumption since you talked about making a http request to a "database" server, but maybe it's just how you worded it). Most people by convention keep them on separate servers to improve resilience, security and performance, and allow things like clustered webservers more easily.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was a combination of the following:

- Firewall SNAT was not configured correctly
- Hosts file also not configured correctly
- Changes needed to the application to allow CORS

We eventually (after a few years) created a new MVC REST API Service. So I can't recall what application changes were made to make it work at the time.

This is our current Cors application code that makes it work.

In the App_Start -> WebApiConfig class for both the security service and the final (server) service application

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        EnableCorsAttribute enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```